# Jenkins Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin to return build number

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins with the Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin. Once I kick off a remote build I would immediately like to get the build number of that remote job.

If I inspect the console output of the remote job that is running I can see "This job is build #[1234] on the remote server."

Is there a way of grabbing that job number? I don't want to wait until job completion to get the information.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the build number with the environment variable `BUILD_NUMBER` in a shell script. You can have a look at the [Jenkins Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Doesn't BUILD_NUMBER show me the number for the job on my Jenkins master? I want to get the build number of the job which is running on the remote Jenkins master.

Comment: Have you tried to display `${BUILD_NUMBER}` in Add build step > Trigger a remote parameterized job > Job Info > Parameters ?